# Cant see the end of the scrollbar when wrapping the main content in a scrollable div

Tags: css

As you can see we cant see the end of the scrollbar, I messed around with the page and i've noticed that if we delete the navbar we can see the end of the scrollbar but i have no idea how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aorw83m1/3/)

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
}
.navbar-header {
  position: relative;
  background: #202124;
  z-index: 10;
}
.navbar-header .navbar .hamburger {
  height: 68px;
  display: none;
}

.navbar-header .navbar ul li {
  height: 68px;
}

.content-wrapper {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
}

.image-header {
  height: calc(100vh - 68px);
}

.main {
  padding: 2rem 0;
}
.main .showcase {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The containers are 100vh, but the div that contains the actual content you need to scroll is smaller than that.

The easiest way to work around this without modifying the HMTL is:

```
.content-wrapper {
    height: 85%; }
```

Comment: Thats not gonna do the trick, if you resize the browser you still cant see the full scrollbar.

Comment: try this: height: calc(100vh - 70px); on the content-wrapper div